# Mongoose - Ref - update parent based on child document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Instead of having sub-documents, as these schemas/models are queried a lot and independently, I decided to use "Ref" feature of Mongoose. The use case is a Job holding multiple Requests, so I have a Job schema and a Request schema like below..

```
const jobSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
      type: Schema.Types.UUID,
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: _.keys(jobStatus),
    },
    requestIds: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.UUID,
        ref: 'Request',
      },
    ],
});
```

and

```
const request = new Schema({
 _id: {
      type: Schema.Types.UUID,
    },
    jobId: {
      type: Schema.Types.UUID,
      ref: 'Job',
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: _.keys(requestStatus),
    },
});
```

The request status are updated independently, but the job status is dependent on the completion of the request status. So, if all the requests are completed, i need to mark the job status as completed. In order to update the job to Completed, i need to look at if all the requests Ids are having the status to completed.
How do I do in Mongoose query/ update, preferably, a single call to the database.

Comment: Could you provide us with more information about your program logic in order to provide a good solution? Why do you have a cross reference in your schemas? If a job has all it´s requests completed but then someone makes another request, then you need to update the job status again, right? Isn´t it better to perform aggregation when fetching the data from the database, and look if all the populated jobs requests are completed?

Comment: Yes your correct, but when the job is already marked complete, i will not allow another request to mark the job again. but you are right, the cross ref may not be needed. i thought it  would be useful to do a GET query for all the job/ request in a single query. For this "update" problem, would $lookup help, is so i do not need the "ref" anymore?